# Instantiate A Property Of Type List<>

Tags: c#

I created a property of type List in my class

```
public List<string> CategoryRef { get; set; }
```

Now when I wanna add a string to the list I try

```
Product p=new Product();
p.CategoryRef.Add("Nick");
```

The compiler yells at me saying the object isnt set to an instance of an object. How to I instantiate a property?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the constructor you need to say

```
this.CategoryRef = new List<string>();
```

All that

```
public List<string> CategoryRef { get; set; }
```

does is declare an auto-property of type `List<string>` named `CategoryRef`. Implicitly behind this auto-property is a backing field, but that backing field receives the default value for objects of type `List<string>`. Therefore, by default, the backing field is `null` and this is why you must set it in the constructor (or somewhere else but before you use it for the first time).

Finally, you probably should not be exposing the setter publicly. At a minimum, it is better to say

```
public List<string> CategoryRef { get; private set; }
```

Do you really want clients of your class to be able to assign a new list to `CategoryRef`? Probably not.

And in situations like this, I actually prefer a manual property so that I can make the backing field readonly.

```
private readonly List<string> categoryRef = new List<string>();
public List<string> CategoryRef {
    get {
        return this.categoryRef;
    }
}
```

Comment: It can be simplified further with auto-property initializer.

Answer (score 3):

In the constructor of the object, you should have a line that sets the property to a new list.

```
public class Product{
   public Product()
   {
      CategoryRef = new List<string>();
   }

   public List<string> CategoryRef{ get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would perhaps try something like the below

```
public class Product{

   public List<string> CategoryRef{ get; set;} = new List<string>();

}
```